# Cant make get Id for insert with inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, get

here a simple code i used 2 forms with  shows and hide  so everything works great i just missed to set the `CL_ID` on a different table using the second form

so what i needs  here Just  to insert that row result `.$row['cl_id'].` what i'm getting on the 1st query to get inserted on the 2nd form whats  goes right and saved data '
i'm tried  get it up or down all my problem was "undefined Variable" & Other  "undefined index" cause of the `($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data))`

i tried everything but i discover to defined the Variable it should be ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) { only here } any where else the Array not reached not readable

```
<?php
echo"<style type='text/css'>#here{ display:none; } </style> ";
require ('connections.php');
echo"<hr />";
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
   $search=(trim($_POST['search']));
   if (empty($search)){echo" insert something to search it ";
   } else{
     $data=mysql_query("SELECT * from cl_info INNER JOIN cl_pro ON cl_pro.cl_id=cl_info.id WHERE cl_info.id LIKE '$search'")or die(mysql_error());
     $num=mysql_num_rows($data);
         if($num<1){echo' no results of your search'; }

        else{?> <style type="text/css">#form1{ display:none; }</style>
                <style type="text/css">#here{ display:block; }</style>
        <?php




              while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
                //$ak=($row['cl_id'])   ;
//                    echo("<hr/>");
//                     echo("$ak");

 echo("<table with='40%'border='1' align='center'>
  <tr>
  <th>  Client ID</th>
  <th>  Name</th>
  <th>  Phone</th>
  <th>  Date of Birth</th>
  <th>  Blood Type</th>
  <th>  E-mail</th>
  <th>  smoker</th>
  <th>  drugs</th>
  <th>  extra</th>
  <th>  extra2</th>
  </tr>


   <tr>
    <td>".$row['cl_id']."</td>
    <td>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['phon']."</td>
    <td>".$row['d_birth']."</td>
    <td>".$row['blood_typ']."</td>
    <td>".$row['email']."</td>
    <td>".$row['smoker']."</td>
    <td>".$row['drugs']."</td>
     <td>".$row['extra']."</td>
    <td>".$row['extra2']."</td>

     </tr> ") ; echo"</table>";



     } } } }

 echo"  where it was  form 1


<form id='form1' action=''  method='post'>
<input type='text' name='search' />
<input type='submit' name='sub'  /> </form>


  " ;

  /////// start  open  new form2 "here "//////


 echo"
<form  id='here' action=''    method='post' >

r: <input type='text' name='r' />
Doz :<input type='text' name='doz' />
Time:<input type='text' name='t/d' />
Date <input type='text' name='date' />
<input type='hidden' name='cl_id'  />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Insert'  />

</form> ";

      if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
//if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  echo('you have isset works right');

   $r =$_POST['r'];
   $doz =$_POST['doz'];
   $t =$_POST['t/d'];
   $date =$_POST['date'] ;
   //$clid =$_POST['cl_id'] ;

 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO scri (id, cl_id, r, doz, time, date) VALUES ('', '$ak', '$r', '$doz', '$t', '$date')")or die ( mysql_error());

}
?>                                 <!---- end of PHP ---->

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you echo this? mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) What is inside $data?

Comment: @Marijke i can  get the result and every things works  great  Just the CL_id not inserted on the 2nd form

Comment: It's because $ak is empty, look at this in your code:

while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
                //$ak=($row['cl_id'])   ;
//                    echo("<hr/>");
//                     echo("$ak");

Comment: @Marijke when i  use  echo  its  works  and  i can see the result but its  not able  t o inserted on the 2nd  form

Comment: Then try this: mysql_query ("INSERT INTO scri (id, cl_id, r, doz, time, date) VALUES ('', ".$row['cl_id'].", ".$r.", ".$doz.", ".$t.", ".$date.")")or die ( mysql_error());

Comment: @Marijke Notice: Undefined variable: row in  on line 109

Comment: Can you please echo the $ak again, before doing the query? I'm pretty sure $ak = ''

Comment: i tried  everything  but i discover to defined the Variable it should be  ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) { here  } any where else the Array not reached  not readable

Comment: yes  work yes   and   echo  the values  right can i  Upload a picture  or link for a pic here  ?

Comment: @Marijke yes the echo  work , yes and echo  the values but not inserted on the Base  other  wise can i  Upload a picture  or link for a pic here  ?

Comment: Yes that would be great, just upload a printscreen in something like photobucket and share the url.

Comment: @Marijke  http://i41.tinypic.com/x0uzpu.jpg

Comment: @Marijke  http://i43.tinypic.com/fko6d2.jpg

Comment: What is the error, and check $doz also.

Comment: thanks in advanced for everyone  tried to help and  special thanks  for @Marijke

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this:

```
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO scri (id, cl_id, r, doze, time, date) VALUES ('', '$ak', '$r', '$doz', '$t', '$date')")or die ( mysql_error());
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: Sorry  but  dose't work with me :-) doze its works without any edit  cause  its text box

Comment: OK, then try this: $r = 1;
   $doz = 1;
   $t = 1;
   $date = 1;
   $ak = 47;

 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO scri (id, cl_id, r, doze, time, date) VALUES ('', '$ak', '$r', '$doz', '$t', '$date')")or die ( mysql_error());

Comment: Unknown column 'doze' in 'field list'  by Removing the e of  Doz its  Inserted ....